# Can someone explain to me why this code doesn't output anything

Tags: c++, c++17, undefined-behavior

I've already broken my head over what's wrong here. In the output I literally get nothing.
It is very strange that nothing is output through a normal `cout`.

Help me please! Thank you.

```
int main() {
    int x = 111111;
    array<int, 10> numbers;
    numbers.fill(8);
    const auto numbers_copy = numbers;
    int y = 222222;
    
    for (int* i = &y; i <= &x; i++) {
        cout << *i << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: The code has undefined behavior.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do in that for loop?

Comment: @MichaelDorgan iterate over stack

Comment: @toiepp: That's not a thing C++ allows you to do. Not with well-defined behavior.

Comment: @NicolBolas thats not my code, i just saw it in Coursera course and in this course this code works. Thatswhy I'm so confused.

Comment: @NicolBolas in that course this code gave `222222 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 123 0 11111` in output

Comment: If this code is claimed to be correct, then I strongly suggest finding some other learning material.

Comment: @cigien thank you for your advice

Comment: You are in trouble if X and Y are registers.  However, since you take the address of them, they can't be in registers.  They can be in different memory segments, not necessarily the stack.

Comment: To follow up, if you wanted to iterate overall all those elements, they would need to be in a stucture together.  Also not 100% certain at all the array<> doesn't have some glue structures that would prevent this from working.  Then you could take the address of the first element and increment the pointer until it is equal to the last - providing array<> doesn't have a unaligned memory that would cause this to fail.  All told, not at all a good example to be following.

Comment: While iterating over stack is not well defined in general, I see how this is still a useful exercise to understand how the call stack works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This loop:

```
for (int* i = &y; i <= &x; i++) {
```

has [undefined behavior (UB)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comparing pointers to unrelated objects has unspecified results. In this case `i` is pointing to 2 different `int` objects, `x` and `y`, so the first comparison may or may not be true, because there is no guarantee that 2 objects on the stack will be placed one after the other contiguously in memory, or in any particular order.

The same applies to the second iteration of the loop. In the second iteration, when you do `i++` for the second time, this is undefined behavior, since you can't increment `i` that far when it points to an `int`.

Comment: But these are local variables allocated on the stack, so i should be traversing the stack, no? What am I missing?

Comment: you can compare them but you can get either result. UB is inrementing i

Comment: @YuriFeldman You are comparing pointers of unrelated variables. There is no guarantee to what order variables on the stack are placed. You are *assuming* that `y` has a lower memory address than `x`, but that may not actually be true. Only memory addresses of elements belonging to the same array can be traversed like this in a well-defined way. Otherwise, put the variables into a `class`/`struct` instead, and then traverse the memory of that object as needed.

Comment: But they normally are, aren't they? So possibly on OP's machine stack grows the other way around? Thanks!

Comment: not sure but I interpret this https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.rel#4.3 as you can get true or false, but comparing them is valid

Comment: @idclev463035818 Hmm, interesting. The increment of `i` is allowed once actually, it's considered one past the end. Not sure about the comparison.

Comment: @idclev463035818 Edited the answer to explain where the UB actually comes from.